# ANDROID: How to calculate difference between two significant changes in light sensor data?

Tags: android, gesture, android-sensors, light-sensor

I am trying to calculate the number of troughs, that is number of times the sensor value goes drastically down, and then up to achieve a down-up (bringing hand near the phone, and then taking it away) hand gesture. This is what I am trying.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ..........
        .........

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                printValue();
                new Handler().postDelayed(this, 5000);
            }
        }, 5000);

    }

    public void printValue(){
        textView.setText(" "+arr);
        int count = calculateTrough();
        textView1.setText("Number of troughs: "+count);

        arr.clear();
    }

    public int calculateTrough(){
        int count = 0;

        if(arr == null){
            count = 0;
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                if (arr.get(i) - arr.get(i + 1) > 5.00 && arr.get(i + 2) - arr.get(i + 1) > 5.00)
                    count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        if(sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT){
            arr.add(sensorEvent.values[0]);
        }
    }
```

Is this the correct approach? The app seems to crash whenever I try to run it in my phone. Upon debugging, it is due to the forloop in the calculateTrough method but I am not able to figure out why. How else should I do it?

Comment: May be you changing array within EventListener while looping through it which changes its size, so need to freeze it when inside for loop.. Also possible array outbounds errors due to if check not capturing it..

Comment: @numbtongue i tried to freeze the array by storing it in a new temp array for it to perform on calculateTrough(). It still crashes! What is the other way ? 
Also, what check are you talking about ?

Comment: @numbtongue both my variables were final. 

Do you have a better way to do it ?

Comment: Remove if and see if it will still crash, also changing i < arr.size() - 1 inside for condition..

Comment: You can probably just use TYPE_PROXIMITY for what you need, just set a label and increment it from within onSensorChanged event https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-advanced-course-practicals/unit-1-expand-the-user-experience/lesson-3-sensors/3-1-p-working-with-sensor-data/3-1-p-working-with-sensor-data.html